# Submitting multiple files to ASP.NET controller accepting an ICollection<IFormFile>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, fetch-api, iformfile

In my ASP.NET Core backend, I have a controller function that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("documents/upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFile(ICollection<IFormFile> files)
{
   ...
}
```

In my front-end, I call the function like this:

```
var postSettings = {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    mode: 'cors'
}
uploadDocuments( files ) {
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('files', files);   
    postSettings.body = data;

    return fetch(endPoint + '/documents/upload', postSettings);
}
```

If "files" is a single file - not an array with one file, but a single File object - `UploadFile` is called with an `ICollection<IFormFile>` containing the single file.

If "files" is a list of files, either a FileList or an array of File objects, `UploadFile` is called with an empty `ICollection<IFormFile>`.

How do I submit a list of files in such a way that they can be parsed as an `ICollection<IFormFile>`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Reference [Uploading multiple files at once - with Fetch](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2016/05/10/uploading-multiple-files-at-once-with-fetch)

```
uploadDocuments(endPoint, files) {
    var postSettings = {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include',
        mode: 'cors'
    };
    var data = new FormData();
    if(files.length > 0) {
        for(var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {
            // the name has to be 'files' so that .NET could properly bind it
            data.append('files', files.item(x));    
        }
    } 
    postSettings.body = data;

    return fetch(endPoint + '/documents/upload', postSettings);
}
```

Reference [Uploading small files with model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads#uploading-small-files-with-model-binding)

> When uploading files using model binding and the `IFormFile`
> interface, the action method can accept either a single `IFormFile` or
> an `IEnumerable<IFormFile>` (or `List<IFormFile>`) representing
> several files. The following example loops through one or more
> uploaded files, saves them to the local file system, and returns the
> total number and size of files uploaded.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("documents/upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
    long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

    // full path to file in temp location
    var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

    foreach (var formFile in files)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
        }
    }

    // process uploaded files
    // Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

    return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath});
}
```