# Upload all files in folder directory to Google Cloud Storage without loop

Tags: c#, google-cloud-storage

How to upload all files in folder to Google Storage Cloud without loop.
Here I try use C# with one file upload :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
    string contentRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

    var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(contentRootPath + "/credentials.json"));

    StorageClient storageClient = StorageClient.Create(credential);

    var objectName = MakeObjectName();

    var imageObject = await storageClient.UploadObjectAsync(
        bucket: CloudConfig.BUCKET,
        objectName: objectName,
        contentType: file.ContentType,
        source: file.OpenReadStream(),
        options: new UploadObjectOptions { PredefinedAcl = PredefinedObjectAcl.PublicRead }
    );

    return Ok(new DropzoneInfo { Name = file.FileName, ObjectName = objectName, Link = imageObject.MediaLink, Size = file.Length});
}
```

Comment: Is there a problem with the code you have shown?

Comment: No problem with the code. Example only.

Comment: then can you elaborate on the problem of extending this to multiple files?

Comment: I just want to question code in block upload to Google Cloud Storage. Not all code in Action.

Comment: And what exactly is your question? At the moment I see a couple possibilities: a) you want to know how to get a list of files in a directory. b) you want to know how to loop through a list uploading each file.

Comment: I don't want to loop through a list uploading each file. I want only one command line to upload all the files in the directory.

Comment: And I want a toilet made out of solid gold, but it's just not in cards now is it? ([Reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHnlKzGbqZc)). Your options are: 1. Use a loop. 2. Petition Google to add a "folder upload" method.

Comment: If you need to do this in a lot of places, make an extension method on the StorageClient or something.

Answer (score 1):

You have a controller action that accepts a single uploaded file. Use a `List<IFormFile>` in your controller action - see this answer: [Submitting multiple files to ASP.NET controller accepting an ICollection<IFormFile>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455994/submitting-multiple-files-to-asp-net-controller-accepting-an-icollectioniformfi)

There is an attribute for uploading directories: `<input type="file" webkitdirectory>` ([How do I use Google Chrome 11's Upload Folder feature in my own code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826286/how-do-i-use-google-chrome-11s-upload-folder-feature-in-my-own-code/5849341#5849341))

These browsers support it: Edge, Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Opera (https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-file-directory)

Comment: I just want to question about Google Cloud Storage, not html, c# and other related upload files from front end to back end.

Comment: @NguyenHung If you want to know if there is a way to upload multiple files in GCS, as you can see in [this example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/api/Storage/Storage.cs ), there is none. What you would need to do is to use some kind of loop.