# List<IFormFile> null when trying to upload

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, file-upload

Team member and I have been working on getting a multiple file upload component working in react with a asp.net back-end. Team member wrote the back-end, so I do have limited knowledge of exactly what the api is doing, but when we send a request using Postman, the file does arrive and is visible in the model debugger.

I've tried various ways of sending the files from my React front-end, including sending as a direct copy of the state, sending as an array with additional information, and sending as a set of independent files, as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43455994/submitting-multiple-files-to-asp-net-controller-accepting-an-icollectioniformfi).

Yes, the form is using

```html
<form encType="multipart/form-data"/>
```

but the file upload itself is obfuscated behind a DropZone component that I designed.

Team member and I are both fairly new to React and are getting frustrated with this detail.

API Call:

```
const data = new FormData(form);
for(var i=0; i <this.state.files.length; i++){
    filesArray.push('files'+ i, this.state.files.item(i));
}
data.append("files", filesArray); 

fetch('http://localhost:5824/api/Claim', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data,
});
```

relevant portion of the DropZone in the form:

```
<input ref={this.fileInputRef} className="dropInput" type="file" multiple onChange={this.onFilesAdded}/>
<span>Upload Files</span>
```

Comment: Ever tried to specify `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',` in your fetch options explicitly?

Comment: What is your Controller action? Is there any demo to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was to add name="files" to the DropZone component.

```html
<input ref={this.fileInputRef} className="dropInput" type="file" name="files" multiple onChange={this.onFilesAdded}/>
```

Do not append the files to FormData from the component state.